# How to specify Parse.Cloud.beforeSave for a specific class?

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In some cloud code, I use a Parse.Cloud.beforeSave method.
I want to use this method only for a specific class named "mySpecialClass".

I tried code syntax like:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("mySpecialClass", function(request, response)
```

and:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(mySpecialClass, function(request, response)
```

But in both case the method gets run for any class and this is not what I want.

What should I do to have my Parse.Cloud.beforeSave method run only for for mySpecialClass and leave alone the other classes?

Comment: Your code is correct. This code is launch on when you save and update your class.

Comment: Yes thanks. The problem disappeared later on, without changing the metohd. My impression of having this method execute whatever the class was probably a side effect of some sort, due to an external cause.